# finding maximum value from a given bits

Tags: java, binary

// a program tells the maximum value we can store in (unsigned integer) a given bits .( 256 for 8 bits)

```
    int counter=0;
    int last= 0b11111111;
    for(int first=0b00000000;first<=last;counter++)
    {
    first=first + 1;//adding 1(binary addition)

    }

    System.out.println("for "+ variable  "bits u can store "+counter values");
```

//variable here 8.
//(1.how to get it from user? 2.how to convert it into binary 0b00000000?)

//how to do this without 0b ,actually in previous version of java
//a program in which if you give 8 bit(in case of unsigned) then it give u maximum values u can store in it, not by using ((2*n)-1).

//code is not only for java 8
// sorry i do not have java 8 i hope the above code will compile without error
thank you in advance

Comment: This Questions is unclear for some of my peers their. But some people  trying to help me by giving codes and through.I am not a native English speaker if u find a problem in questions please comment let others to do their work.Holding questions gives nothing to any of us.Because you can see some people understand my question and gave their answer so think about it.If possible you just modify this question in a proper way.but i need to improve my English Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`long result = 1 << numBits;`

If numBits is greater than the size of long, use a double instead (and cast the "1" and "numBits" to double).

Comment: not clear. I am asking for a code .Anyway thank you

Comment: that is code.  What more would you like the code to do?

Comment: If User typed 8 bits , we store it in a int variable .               1 How can we convert it into  0b00000000?

Comment: No need.  The syntax 0b000... is for humans only to tell the compiler.  Inside the computer, the base doesn't matter.  To answer the question "how many values can <n> bits hold", "1 << n" is the easiest way to get the answer, as long as "n" is not too large.

Comment: by the way, 0b11 + 1 = the answer for n=2 (4), just as 0b11111111 + 1 = the answer for n=8 (256).

Comment: thank you. but you are using 0b11 .will it run on java 5, i heard 0b is comes with java8 only. i try to compute this addition without using 0b . Means try to manually convert int 8 into 11111111 and addition operations on it without 0b. Is it possible?

Comment: remember, 0b11 is just binary for the decimal value 3.  Rather than typing 11111111, try 255 ;-).

Answer (score 1):

how about this

```
int last = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < bitNum; i++){
    last = (last << 1) + 1
}
```

Comment: If user query for 8 bits .we store it in a int variable1. how can we convert it into 0b11111111.?

Comment: ok, please wait a minute

Comment: sorry 1. what is bitNum here? 2. I need a Full code which will run not only on java8 and its ascenders too.

Comment: ok take your time. no urgent thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
int variable = s.nextInt();
int counter = 0;
long last = (1 << variable) - 1;// = 0b'111....111
for(int first = 0; i <= last; counter++){
    first = first + 1;
}
System.out.println("for "+ variable +"bits u can store " + counter + "values");
```

this code is same with your code, but this code dont use 0b.